# IOS 7 Region monitoring - choosing your regions

Tags: ios, core-location, region-monitoring

My app wants to monitor more than the max 20 regions.  Is there some way to use current location to determine proximity to any of n defined and non-monitored regions and then populate your monitored regions based on the current location?

Putting it another way, if device is at location X, then load region 1 through 20.  But if the app starts at location y, then you may want to load regions 4 through 23...

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of regions in your app then you can use [`distanceFromLocation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a) to determine which ones are the closest and register those.  You can also implement [signification location change notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) to review your region distances and select different regions to monitor when the device moves.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I'm quite new to IOS and didn't pick up on that method.  I was considering taking the full geo area and defining large regions with slight overlap, to cover the entire space.  Then use locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion to determine which of those temp regions the device was in, drop all those regions and set up those actual regions in proximity that I wanted to monitor.  Not sure didDetermine really does what I think it does.  Your's is a better solution.